# Передача данных из формы

Tags: c#

Передаю данные из первой формы во вторую Выдает ошибку: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

```
//Form1
    public FormChoise FormChoise1;
    FormChoise1 = new FormChoise();
    FormChoise1.InputString = "M|G";
    FormChoise1.Owner = this;
    FormChoise1.Show();

    public void DelMess(int hap_del, string source_)
    {"hi"}

//Form2
    public string InputString;
    Form1 formMain;                    //равен null
    string OutString = "hi";
    formMain.DelMess(1, OutString);    //Ошибка: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта
```

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете перегрузить нужную форму и передавать туда ссылку/объект.

К примеру хотим открыть форму 2 и там задать нужное значение (В данном примере мы в `Form2` передаем необходимый нам объект, который дальше присваиваем к нужной, внутренней переменной, что позволит нам без труда использовать ее в дальнейшем):

```
private string Value;
public Form2(string val)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Value = val;
}
```

И вызов:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2("Hello!");
form2.Show();
```

---

Другой пример, хотим запустить `Form2` и из нее вызвать нужное нам из `Form1` (В данном примере мы можем передать ссылку на первую форму и работать с ней):

```
public Form2(Form1 form)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form.MyMethod("World!");
}
```

Форма 1:

```
//...
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
//...

public void MyMethod(string aa)
{
    MessageBox.Show(aa);
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что значение во второй форме я получаю, но не могу присвоить результат вычислений в переменную первой формы, те не могу обратно передать. `string OutString = "hi"; formMain.DelMess(1, OutString); `, где последняя `public void DelMess(int hap_del, string source_)
    {"hi"}`на этом месте выходит ошибка: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Comment: @zayana Ну вы понимаете, что написав `Form1 formMain;` - вы только создаете пустой объект, не инициализировав его (`= new Form1();), это вам дает ошибку. Вам надо либо инициализировать как я только что написал (если форма еще не открыта), либо из первой формы передать ссылку на эту форму в нужную форму (как я указал в ответе) и уже затем ее использовать.

Comment: Все оказалось проще простого, спасибо что откликнулись!