# взять данные из другого формы через user control (winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Добрый день. Есть одна  форма и user control. В  форме есть tabcontrol с tabPages. а user control надо записывать. Я с помощью класса TabControl хотел попробовать выдаёт ошибка. Можно ли вызывать элементы формы из usercontrol? Теперь значение Id берётся, но при заказе Id обнуляется.

Вот код:

UserControl.cs

```
   public int index;
    public void InsertIndex(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }


public void InsertTempOutcomes()
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO TempOutcomes(RoomId,UserId,NameGoods,PriceGoods,AmountGoods,DataStart,DataFinish) VALUES((SELECT Name FROM Rooms WHERE Id=@roomId),(SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Id=@userId),(SELECT Name FROM Store WHERE Id=@id),(SELECT Price FROM Store WHERE Id=@id),@amount,@dataStart,@dataFinish)";
    int goodsId = comboBoxGoods.SelectedIndex + 1;
    try
    {
        command = new SQLiteCommand(query,connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount",textBoxAmount.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataStart",dateTimePicker.Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", goodsId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataFinish", dateTimePicker.Value.AddSeconds(seconds));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomId",index);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    finally { connection.Close(); }
}
```

Form.cs

```
        UserContrElems user = new UserContrElems();
        string querySelect = "SELECT Name FROM Rooms WHERE Id=@id";
        int index = tabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1;
        user.InsertIndex(index);
```

Comment: Тут вы создаёте новый `TabControl`, который не помещён на форму и вообще пустой. Думаю, вам нужно обращаться к тому `TabControl`, который уже есть на форме.

Comment: тот tabcontrol в другом форме

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев Я недавно [отвечал на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795890/220553), где объяснил как можно передать из формы в форму ссылку на нужную форму при ее создание. Попробуйте так же передать в нужную форму ссылку на ту, где ваш `TabControl` и именно с ней и работать.

Comment: Если не изменяет память, то `TabControl` это всего лишь контейнер в котором находятся `TabPage` вкладки/страницы. Эти вкладки можно переключать и располагать свой набор элементов на каждой из них. Так вот `SelectedIndex` это текущая активная `TabPage` страница/вкладка.

Comment: Rootware я не могу понять как значение обнуляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему. Я создавал новый User Control. Мне надо было использовать уже созданный user control.

```
int index = tabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1;
            switch(index)
            {
                case 1: userContrElems1.Insert(index); break;
                case 2: userContrElems2.Insert(index); break;
                case 3: userContrElems3.Insert(index); break;
                case 4: userContrElems4.Insert(index); break;
                case 5: userContrElems5.Insert(index); break;
                case 6: userContrElems6.Insert(index); break;
            }
```