# Передача цвета из одной формы в другую

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток!Такая проблема: Создалa Form1(там должен меняться цвет), создалa Form2, кинулa туда кнопку, комбо бокс, что-то вроде выпадающего списка с цветами.Как передать данные о цвете из одной формы в другую(Из Form2 в Form1), то есть я в Form2 комбо боксе выбираю цвет, жму на кнопку и в Form1 меняется фон. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать, третий день мучаюсь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795890/220553

Comment: а как-то проще можно, без перегрузки?

Comment: Это самое легкое, что есть, другое - изобретение велосипедов как по мне.. Ну а так, ваша вторая форма должна знать о том месте, где находится ваш цвет. Это может быть класс к примеру или еще что то подобное. Так, как вы уже задаете определенный цвет - объект создан, а значит вам надо передать ссылку на него во вторую форму. Еще есть вариант... Использовать static переменную, но это как по мне - костыль...