# Теряется значение переменной при смене формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы, form1 и form 3. В форм 1 создаю public строковую переменную fam:

```
public string fam;
```

После чего передаю в неё результат запроса:

```
fam = oleComm2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(fam);
```

Значение переменной показывает верно. В форм 3 создаю экземпляр класса форм 1, создаю переменную faml и присваиваю ей значение fam:

```
Form1 fr1 = new Form1();
string faml = fr1.fam;
MessageBox.Show(faml);
```

После чего в месседжбоксе показывается null значение. Подскажите, как сохранить переменную при переходе между формами.

Comment: Ну дык вы же новую форму создали, соответственно у нее переменная новая. Используйте тот же экземпляр Form1, а не создавайте новый.

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть в коде не подскажите? Я не очень понимаю как обратиться к дефолтному экземпляру Form1, он был создан по умолчанию.

Comment: Что значит создан по умолчанию?

Comment: При создание `form3` передавайте в нее ссылку на объект `form1` (я о таком писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795890/220553)), это самый легкий вариант.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача данных из формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795870/c-%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: @tym32167 ну у созданного мною экземпляра формы Form1 имя fr1, а как обратиться к самому первому экземпляру формы?

Comment: @Georg96, вы посмотрели вопрос по ссылке?

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо за ссылку, начал разбираться.

Comment: Почему бы вам не сделать переменную статической?

Comment: @Uranus, так и сделал и всё заработало. Обратился к экземпляру Form1.fam и всё передалось. Скажите, а зачем тогда использовать более сложные способы, как предложили выше, если можно сделать переменную static?

Comment: `static` - это глобальное состояние и у него свои проблемы, обычно следует его избегать. Подробное объяснение выходит за рамки этой темы. А передачу параметров надо понимать не как более сложный способ, а как правильный способ. Еще более правильно будет отделить логику GUI от логики работы с БД и прочих бизнес-процессов. В частности, смотрите паттерн MVP.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, в таком случае отмечаю вопрос дубликатом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поле `string fam` не статическое, поэтому каждый экземпляр класса `Form1` будет иметь свое поле и разные значения. Если нам нужен "тот первый экземпляр", то нужно получить его, например, через параметр конструктора. Для этого измените конструктор в форме Form3:

```
Form1 form;

public Form3(Form1 form)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.form = form;
}
```

Теперь, когда открываете форму, передавайте ей ссылку на Form1. Если вы открываете Form3 из Form1, то ссылка как раз будет в `this`:

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3(this);
....
```

А когда вам понадобятся данные из Form1 в коде Form3, не создавайте новый экземпляр, а воспользуйтесь уже имеющейся ссылкой:

```
string faml = form.fam;
MessageBox.Show(faml);
```