# Как из From2 выбраный елемент comboBox загнать в DataGridView Form1 в колонку

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

FORM2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

            DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem);

            this.Close();
        }
```

FORM1

```
public string Doc { get; set; }

        public void DoctorName(string DocName)
        {

            Doc = DocName;

        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Имя пациента";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Фамилия пациента";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Возраст";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Диагноз";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Лечащий врач";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddData(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text,textBox4.Text);

        }

        private void AddData(string name,string lastName,string age,string diagnose)
        {
            string[] data = { name, lastName, age.ToString(), diagnose};
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data);

            Form2 formDoctor = new Form2();
            formDoctor.Show();

        }
```

Comment: И [еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795870/Передача-данных-из-формы/795890#795890)...

Comment: Это не совсем то, просмотри код, я знаю как ссылки на формы создавать
Я не знаю как добавить текст в колонку

Comment: И в чем проблема тогда? По вашему коду мало что можно понять.

Comment: Не понимаю как обратится к рядку датагрид из другой формы

Comment: А говорите, что умеете. Я вам дал ответ на ваш вопрос, смотрите внимательней.

Comment: Я понимаю что типо так
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            
            frm1.dataGridView1....
Но интелиссенс не видит его

Comment: Чтоб из одной формы увидеть какой-либо контрол другой формы нужно у этого контрола выставить свойство `Modifiers` в `Internal`

Comment: Вообщем передал параметр из второй формы в первую, вот только почему то оно не меняет форму 1 после добавления значения
Хотя DocName меняется в дебагере
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Column4"].Value = DocName;
Как еще можно добавить значение DocName в последние столбики?