# Вызов переменной из другого класса

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно вызывать переменную oX из класса Form1 в классе points2Dcalc

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void input()
    {
    int oX = pictureBox1.Width / 2;
    int oY = pictureBox1.Height / 2;
    }
}
public class points2Dcalc
    {
        public int X, Y;

        public points2Dcalc(int _x, int _y)
        {
            X = oX - _x;
            Y = oY + _y;    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача данных из формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795870/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете размер контрола на форме в качестве константы. Сделать надо наоборот. Завести константу и использовать ее, чтобы установить размер контрола на форме, а также во всех других местах.

```
public class Const_Size
{
  public const int WIDTH = 200;
  public static int CENTER_X { get { return WIDTH / 2; } }
  public const int HEIGHT = 200;
  public static int CENTER_Y { get { return HEIGHT / 2; } }
}

public class points2Dcalc
{
  public int X, Y;

  public points2Dcalc(int _x, int _y)
  {
    X = Const_Size.CENTER_X - _x;
    Y = Const_Size.CENTER_X + _y;    
  }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      pictureBox1.Width  = Const_Size.WIDTH;
      pictureBox1.Height = Const_Size.HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Классно! Спасибо большое

Comment: @Alexander На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: Будем дальше учиться)